# Get rid of blue line using ActionBarCompat

Tags: android, themes, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm using the ActionBarCompat library, and I've got a custom theme I've created from the [Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/). The background is set to a custom image provided by this, but the blue line is still there! This happens on both 2.2+ and 4.0+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, as it turns out I didn't set my app's theme to the one created by the generator.